# Unexpected response code 500 for when calling C# web services

Tags: java, android

**Here is the web service link: 
geting error 500 when calling the webservice...is there anything wrong with my codes? that i need to change?

the web service is running fine in the browser

http://www.spgautopark.com.my/spgservices/parking_registration.asmx?op=Signup**

**Registration**

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




    Button signup;
    TextView login;

   EditText edt_name,edt_phone,edt_mail,edt_vehno,edt_pwd,edt_cpwd;
    String email;

    String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";



    String name,phone,mail,pwd,vehno;
    String deviceId;
    String Result, Message, Username,cid,Email,Mobile, address;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);
        context = this;




        deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), deviceId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signaccount);
        login= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);



        edt_name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

        edt_phone= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);

        edt_mail= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mail);

        edt_vehno= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vehno);
        edt_pwd= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd);


        edt_cpwd= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cpwd);




        login.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Login</u>"));





        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {





                email = edt_mail.getText().toString().trim();

               /* if (emailText.getText().length() != 0) {

                } else {
                    emailText.setError("Invalid Email");


                }*/

                if (edt_name.getText().length() == 0) {
                    edt_name.setError("Enter name");


                }




                else if (edt_phone.getText().length() != 10) {
                    edt_phone.setError("Enter Mobile no");

                }


                if (email.matches(emailPattern) && email.length() > 0) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "valid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // or
                    //textView.setText("valid email");
                } else {

                    edt_mail.setError("Invalid email");
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //or
                    // textView.setText("invalid email");
                }
                if (edt_vehno.getText().length() == 0) {
                    edt_vehno.setError("Enter vehno");


                }


                else if (edt_pwd.getText().length() == 0) {
                    edt_pwd.setError("Enter Password");
                }
                else if (edt_cpwd.getText().length() == 0) {
                    edt_cpwd.setError("Enter Re-Type Password");


                }
                else if (edt_pwd.getText().toString().equals(edt_cpwd.getText().toString())) {

                    if ((edt_name.getText().length() != 0) && (edt_mail.getText().length() != 0) && (edt_vehno.getText().length() != 0)
                            && (edt_phone.getText().length() != 0) && (edt_pwd.getText().length() != 0)
                            && (edt_cpwd.getText().length() != 0) && (email.matches(emailPattern) && email.length() > 0)) {
                        Log.e("testing", "before user data class");
                        registerUser();
                        //openProfile();


                    }


                }

                else

                {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Missmatch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }


                // Start the Activity_Signup activity

                /*Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
                 //((Activity_Login) context).finish();
                startActivity(intent);
*/
               /* HomeFragment fragment4 = new HomeFragment();


                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction4 =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                fragmentTransaction4.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment4);

                fragmentTransaction4.commit();
*/
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start the Activity_Signup activity

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                //((Activity_Login) context).finish();
                startActivity(intent);

               /* HomeFragment fragment4 = new HomeFragment();


                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction4 =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                fragmentTransaction4.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment4);

                fragmentTransaction4.commit();
*/
            }
        });


    }


//---------------------------------Registration Method------------------------------------------------//

    private void registerUser(){





        name = edt_name.getText().toString().trim();

        phone = edt_phone.getText().toString().trim();

        mail= edt_mail.getText().toString().trim();
        //phone = edt_pwd.getText().toString();
        pwd =edt_pwd.getText().toString().trim();
        vehno = edt_vehno.getText().toString().trim();
//The above values u need to pass to the SIGNUP_URL...

        //utype = spstring;

//correct code
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, End_Urls.SIGNUP_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Log.e("sinup response testing", "json response = "+response);

                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonArray1 = new JSONObject(response);

                            Log.e("jsonArray1", "json jsonArray1 = "+jsonArray1);


                            Result = jsonArray1.getString("status");
                            Message = jsonArray1.getString("response");


                            //name1 = jsonArray1.getString("user_id");
                            //email1 = jsonArray1.getString("user_id");
                            //password1 = jsonArray1.getString("user_id");
                            //phone1 = jsonArray1.getString("user_id");
                            //area1 = jsonArray1.getString("user_id");
                            cid = jsonArray1.getString("register_id");
                            //oname1 = jsonArray1.getString("user_id");

                            Log.e("testing","Result == "+Result);
                            Log.e("testing","Message == "+Message);
                            //Log.e("testing","RegisterName == "+JsonName);
                            Log.e("mahi cid testing","RegisterId == "+cid);




                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            //Log.e("testing","Exception =" + e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Log.e("testing", "json response=="+response);

                        if (Result.equals("yes")) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e("testing", "Message111==" + Message);
                            openProfile();
                        }

                        else if (Result.equals("null"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e("testing", "Message222=="+Message);
                            Intent intentN = new Intent(SignupActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);

                            ((SignupActivity) context).finish();
                            //intent.putExtra(KEY_PHONENO, phoneno);
                            startActivity(intentN);

                        }

                        else if (Result.equals("No")){

                            Log.e("testing", "json response == " + response);
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, Message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);

                            //((Activity_Login) context).finish();
                            //intent.putExtra(KEY_PHONENO, phoneno);
                            startActivity(intent);


                        }








                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this,Message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                        Log.e("testing","error response == " +
                                ""+error);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                        //intent.putExtra(KEY_PHONENO, phoneno);
                        startActivity(intent);



                    }
                })


        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put(End_Urls.Signup_username,name);
                params.put(End_Urls.Signup_phone,phone);
                params.put(End_Urls.Signup_email, email);
                params.put(End_Urls.Signup_vehno, vehno);
                params.put(End_Urls.Signup_deviceid, pwd);
                params.put(End_Urls.Signup_pwd, pwd);
                params.put(End_Urls.Signup_deviceid, deviceId);
                //params.put(End_Urls.Signup_deviceid, "deviceIdtesting");
                //params.put(UrlEndpoints.KEY_user_type, spstring);
                Log.e("testing", "params11==" + params);

                return params;

            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }




    private void openProfile(){


       /* final String name = _userNameText.getText().toString().trim();

        final String email = emailText.getText().toString().trim();

        final String password = _passwordText.getText().toString().trim();


        final String area = areaText.getText().toString().trim();
        final String oname = onameText.getText().toString().trim();

*/
        Intent intentN = new Intent(SignupActivity.this,Activity_Verify_Phone.class);


        intentN.putExtra("cid", cid);

        //((Activity_Signup) context).finish();
        //intent.putExtra(KEY_PHONENO, phoneno);
        startActivity(intentN);



    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code , put your parameter and result on the map

```
public void HttpPOSTRequestWithParameters() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://www.spgautopark.com.my/spgservices/parking_registration.asmx?op=Signup";
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
            new Response.Listener<String>() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                }
            }, 
            new Response.ErrorListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("ERROR","error => "+error.toString());
                }
            }
                ) {     
            // this is the relevant method
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
            {  
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("grant_type", "password"); 
                // volley will escape this for you 
                params.put("keys", "values");
                params.put("put keys", "values");  
                params.put("keys", "valuers");

                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(postRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jai, you mean i remove my original code use the one you just post?

Comment: yah try this one

Comment: having error on this.. RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); the (this)  showing in volley cannot be apply